# Malcev closure of Lie algebra.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> [Onishichik, Vinberg, Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups, Chapter 1, Section 4, Exercises 6).]Let $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ be subalgebras of the tangent algebra of a Lie group such that $[\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}] \subset \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$. Let $\mathfrak{a}^{M}, \mathfrak{b}^{M}$ be their Malcev closures. Then $\left[\mathfrak{a}^{M}, \mathfrak{b}^{M}\right]=[\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}]$. (Here $[\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}]$ is the subspace generated by the brackets $[\xi, \eta]$, where $\xi \in \mathfrak{a}, \eta \in \mathfrak{b}$)

Malcev closure: $\mathfrak{a}^M := \operatorname{Lie}\left(\bigcap_{H \in \Sigma} H\right) = \bigcap_{H \in \Sigma} \operatorname{Lie}(H)$, where $\Sigma=\{H\leqslant G \mid \mathfrak{a}\subset \operatorname{Lie}(H)\}$, that is, the tangent algebra of the smallest subgroup of $G$ such that its tangent algebra contains $\mathfrak{a}$.

Hence clearly $[\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}] \subset [\mathfrak{a}^M,\mathfrak{b}^M]$. How to show the converse direction?
Thank you!